# Alias returns true 404, not custom sitecore 404 page

Tags: untagged

I have a sitecore 7.2 site. It has a custom 404 set with a patch file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
<settings>
  <setting name="ItemNotFoundUrl">
    <patch:attribute name="value">/other/404</patch:attribute>
  </setting> 
</settings>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

I am using aliases and some of them work and some do not. In some cases, I have nested aliases, meaning I have an alias Foo with a child alias Bar so the url would be /Foo/Bar. The child item has the link back to an actual page. Sometimes this works and sometimes it does not and I cannot figure out why its not working. In the cases where it doesn't work, I get an IIS 404 and not my custom 404

[image: 404 image not found]

**UPDATE**

Some new information. It seems that it is these specific aliases that are a problem. I can create new ones to do the same thing and they work fine. I can find nothing different about these specific aliases, even looking at the raw values. But they do not work.

[image]

There is nothing in logs related to this 404.
I got a copy of the IIS trace for the failing request. Its actually looking for a file on the drive named the same as the alias, which obviously fails:

261. -FILE_CACHE_ACCESS_START

FileName
E:\MyWebsiteFolder\Website\vocrules\k12

UserName
IUSR

DomainName
NT AUTHORITY

0 ms

Informational
262.  -FILE_CACHE_ACCESS_END

Successful
false

FileFromCache
false

FileAddedToCache
false

FileDirmoned
true

LastModCheckErrorIgnored
true

ErrorCode
The system cannot find the path specified.
 (0x80070003)

LastModifiedTime

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot with some examples of the aliases you have in place so I can setup a test and try to reproduce the issue you are seeing?

Comment: Have you checked logs to see if it's actually crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden in my patch files was an IgnoreUrlPrefix for the prefix in question: vocrules. No idea why it was there. I deleted that particular prefix and all was well.